# Is there a possibility of creating an active "firewall" on a pen drive?

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, anti-virus

What I'd like to do is build a program which will be installed onto a pen drive. This program would then notify the user of any program which tries to access the pen drive for read/write purposes. The user would have the privilege to either grant or refuse these requests.

As far as I've come up with search, there doesn't seem to be any way to do this without having to install something else on the computer the pen drive is inserted into. Is it possible to make such a program solely dependent on the pen drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: No. This is not possible with a regular pen drive.

If you could write a program and store it on the pen drive then it is just data. It is not active and it does not do anything.

In order for any program to intervene it would need to run. Normally that is the OS of your computer. Thus you would either need to start it or install if on the target computer. If you start it from the pen drive then the drive would be vulnerable until you did that.

The reason that I started this post with *a regular pen drive* is that you can use a non-standard USB device which acts as a read only pen drive and which needs a special drive installed before writing is allowed. There are several like these, mostly sold as 'secure pen drive'. Alternatively you could program an USB device with mass storage to do that for you (You might be able to do this with a [RubberDucky](http://www.usbrubberducky.com/) ).

Once more: You can not do this with a regular pen drive without installing software prior to using the pen drive.

Comment: Perhaps I could just store the .exe file in it and write an autorun.inf file? Would that work?

Comment: Yes and no. No 1) You could still write to the pen drive until the exe started. And you would probably need admin rights to run it. No 2) This is how mosy viruses got distributed and as a result all modern OS's block this.  3 yes) If you got an ancient machine or you already have control over the host then you can do this. But then it is not easier than just installing the driver once.